# Learning JavaScript, how to print out this line only if following statements are true

Tags: javascript

I have too
write a series of complex logical expressions that prints **only if** the following conditions are *true*:

if flavor is set to vanilla or chocolate and
if vessel is set to cone or bowl and
if toppings is set to sprinkles or peanuts
If the above conditions are *true*, then print out:

I'd like two scoops of __________ ice cream in a __________ with __________.

So I entered the following code

```js
var flavor = "chocolate";
var vessel = "bowl";
var toppings = "peanuts";


if (flavor === "chocolate" || flavor === "vanilla" && flavor != "strawberry" &&
  vessel === "cone" ||
  vessel === "bowl" && vessel != "hand" && toppings === "peanuts" ||
  toppings === "sprinkles" && toppings != "walnuts") {
  console.log("I'd like two scoops of " + flavor + " ice cream in a " +
    vessel + " with " + toppings + " .");
}
```

And get the following feedback

Try Again

**What Went Well**

- Your code should have a variable flavor
- Your code should have a variable vessel
- Your code should have a variable toppings
- Your code should have an if statement
- Your code should use logical expressions
- Your code should work with flavor=vanilla, vessel=cone, and toppings=sprinkles
- Your code should work with flavor=vanilla, vessel=cone, and toppings=peanuts
- Your code should work with flavor=vanilla, vessel=bowl, and toppings=sprinkles
- Your code should work with flavor=vanilla, vessel=bowl, and toppings=peanuts
- Your code should work with flavor=chocolate, vessel=cone, and toppings=sprinkles
- Your code should work with flavor=chocolate, vessel=cone, and toppings=peanuts
- Your code should work with flavor=chocolate, vessel=bowl, and toppings=sprinkles
- Your code should work with flavor=chocolate, vessel=bowl, and toppings=peanuts
- List item

**What Went Wrong**

- Your code should not pass when "strawberry" is used as the flavor.
- Your code should not pass when "hand" is used as the vessel.
- Your code should not pass when "walnuts" is used as the topping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work.

```js
var flavor = "chocolate";
var vessel = "bowl";
var toppings = "peanuts";

if (
  (flavor === "chocolate" || flavor === "vanilla") &&
  (vessel === "cone" || vessel === "bowl") &&
  (toppings === "peanuts" || toppings === "sprinkles")
) {
  console.log("I'd like two scoops of " +
    flavor + " ice cream in a " +
    vessel + " with " +
    toppings + " .");
}
```

We don't need to specify all the flavors, vessels and toppings we don't need to use. So if you set the flavor to `strawberry`, the program will look at the first part of the code: *okay, what we got here? Is the flavor equal to chocolate? Nope. Next, is the flavor equal to vanilla? Nope. Okay, this was the required condition so no need to check further, I'll stop executing.*

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code? Just trynna be more understandable

```
function makeMe(flavor,vessel,topping) {
    flavors = ["chocolate","vanilla"];
    cones = ["cone","bowl"];
    toppings = ["sprinkles","peanuts"]
    error1 = error2 = error3 = true;
    for(i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
        if(flavors[i] == flavor) {
            error1 = false;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < cones.length; i++) {
        if(cones[i] == vessel) {
            error2 = false;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < toppings.length; i++) {
        if(toppings[i] == topping) {
            error3 = false;
        }
    }
    if(error1 || error2 || error3) {
        return "We don't have it";
    }
    return "I'd like two scoops of " + flavor + " ice cream in a " + vessel + " with " + toppings + ".";
}
```

Comment: This code may work correctly but I have to notice that it is too complex for the task specified. It can be solved much easier and extra complexity is not needed.

Comment: If you really wanted to do down this road, which probably is a little overkill, it'd be better to use a class